# SSRS is missing after failover to other node

Tags: sql-server, clustering, ssrs-2012

We have 2 node setup cluster, after a failover I can't see the reporting services, even the service it self is missing.

I checked control panel program manager, SSRS is not installed, I open reporting service configuration manager when clicking Find, it can't find the server. Is there a way to retrieve that.

There are active reports already running before the failover.

Sorry I'm new in SSRS, I researched the web and can't find any solution.

Answer (score 5):

Reporting services is not cluster-aware. If you want high-availability you need to set up a scale-out deployment where multiple Report servers share the same back-end database.

From the documentation: [High availability in SQL Server Reporting Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-sharepoint/high-availability-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2017)

> A scale-out deployment provides a way to share a database. If one
>   report server goes down, other servers in the same deployment will
>   continue to work.
>
> Reporting Services is not cluster-aware. By itself, a scale-out
>   deployment does not provide load balancing

So you would have needed to install SSRS on more than one machine and set it up like that before the failover happened.